# How to insert data in many-to-many relationship (Sequelize)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

My Product model:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class Product extends Model {
    static init(connection) {
        super.init({
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
            description: DataTypes.TEXT,
            purchase_price: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
            sale_price: DataTypes.DOUBLE
        }, {sequelize: connection});
    }

    static associate(models) {
        this.belongsToMany(models.Purchase, {
            foreignKey: 'product_id', through: 'products_purchases', as: 'purchases'
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Product;
```

My Purchase Model:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const Product = require('../models/Product');

class Purchase extends Model {
    static init(connection) {
        super.init({
            request_number: DataTypes.STRING,
            datetime: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
            },
                email: DataTypes.STRING,
            status: DataTypes.ENUM([
                'orderPlaced', 'paymentMade','paymentConfirmed', 'forwardedProduct','productReceived','orderCanceled'
            ])
        }, {sequelize: connection});
    }

    static associate(models) {
        this.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'user'});
        this.belongsToMany(models.Product, {
            foreignKey: 'purchase_id', through: 'products_purchases', as: 'products'
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Purchase;
```

And finally my ProductPurchase Model:
(Note that there is some **extra columns** in the relationship table)

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class ProductPurchase extends Model {
    static init(connection) {
        super.init({
            product_value: DataTypes.FLOAT,
            product_quantity: DataTypes.INTEGER
        }, {
            sequelize: connection,
            modelName: 'products_purchases'
        });
    }

}

module.exports = ProductPurchase;
```

I want to insert data into *purchases* table and also into *products_purchases*. I tried to do it the way below, but I don't know how to send the data of the **extra columns** from ProductPurchase:

```
    async store(req, res) {
        try {
            const { user_id } = req.params;
            const user = await User.findByPk(user_id);

            if (!user) {
                return res.status(400).json('User not found!');
            }

            // productsData = [{ productId, productPrice, quantity }];
            const { request_number, datetime, email, status, productsData } = req.body;
            const purchase = await Purchase.create({
                request_number, datetime, email, status, user_id
            });

            const productsIds = productsData.map(product => {
                return product.productId;
            });

            const products = await Product.findAll({
                where: {id: productsIds}
            });


            await purchase.addProduct(products);


            return res.json(products);
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).json(error);
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What error do you get when you run this? I don't think you cant directly insert data into `products_purchases` since you didn't create that model. There are two ways to do a many to many according to sequelize docs. You either let sequelize auto-generate the `products_purchase` model for you(which is what you've done) or you create it yourself which is what I think you want to do?  You could give this a quick read [this](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html).

Comment: that's the error:
```
{
  "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
  "parent": {
    "name": "error",
    "length": 270,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "23502",
    "detail": "Failing row contains (21, 2, null, null, 2020-05-02 21:49:09.925+00, 2020-05-02 21:49:09.925+00).",
    "schema": "public",
    "table": "products_purchases",
    "column": "product_value",
    "sql": "INSERT INTO \"products_purchases\" (\"created_at\",\"updated_at\",\"purchase_id\",\"product_id\") VALUES ('2020-05-02 21:49:09.925 +00:00','2020-05-02 21:49:09.925 +00:00',21,2) RETURNING *;"
  ```

Comment: The error indicates that i have to insert the extra columns values from the ProductPurchase, but I dont know how to do it the right way. I have to insert many rows into the products_purchases table (many products in a purchase). @VIC3KING

Comment: I saw that the right way to insert data in the extra columns from the products_purchases is by the **through** optional parameter:

await purchase.addProduct(product, {through: {product_value: 30, product_quantity: 3}};

But this works just to insert one row. I need to insert many rows in just one request. I dont know if a forEach at products would be a good practice. @VIC3KING

Comment: Yhh If that's the case I think a forEach would work here.